# Testing anonymous async function inside of an RxJS from

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, async-await, rxjs, jestjs

I am failing to find a way of testing the following function:

```
  public toTest(): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(
      async(): Promise<boolean> => {
        return new Promise(resolve => { resolve(true); });
      }
    );
  }
```

Thus far, I've tried something along the usual:

```
  it('coverage toTest()', async (done) => {
    testeeObject.toTest().subscribe(
      result => {
        done();
      }
    );
  });
```

The coverage is as follows:

[image]

How may I conceive a test to get the coverage of this function ?

Note: rewriting the function should be the very last proposition to consider. This is not the real code, I've simplified to make a generic example, the anonymous async function has some more code into it, naturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `rxjs` package, and [mockFn.mockImplementationOnce(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn) to mock the implementation of `from` operator for `rxjs`.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

class MyClass {
  public toTest(): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(
      async (): Promise<boolean> => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(true);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

export { MyClass };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

jest.mock('rxjs', () => {
  return { from: jest.fn() };
});

describe('61272624', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const myclass = new MyClass();
    let input: () => Promise<boolean>;
    const fromMock: any = (o) => {
      // We can get the async function you passed in `from` operator. 
      // Let the input variable keep it, we will execute it later.
      input = o; 
    };
    (from as jest.MockedFunction<typeof from>).mockImplementationOnce(fromMock);
    myclass.toTest();
    const actual = await input!();
    expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61272624/index.test.ts (13.553s)
  61272624
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.565s
```

[image]

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61272624

Comment: Thx for the reply, is it possible not to mock the whole rxjs object in the process ? I have it in use elsewhere.

Comment: @Akheloes Does [jest.resetAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetallmocks) work for your case?

Comment: While the solution is interesting, I have a couple of calls to `rxjs` inside the calling class. Tried with `jest.resetAllMocks` but I am having errors of the folowing type `TypeError: rxjs_1.AsyncSubject is not a constructor`. I'll need to find a way to mock just the `from` function and leave the rest of `rxjs` intact.

Comment: @Akheloes Can you create a new post, provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code and describe your question clearly?

Comment: I'll try and do that if I don't happen to find some solution. However, in simple terms, you can imagine that `MyClass` injects a service which calls the `AsyncSubject` constructor. Mocking `rxjs` erases that constructor and poses a issue. I'll then have to either mock that call as well or find a way to only mock some functions of `rxjs` while still having access to the other functions definitions.

Comment: @Akheloes Also take a look [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename), you can bypass mocking some methods and classes of a package(`rxjs`). After bypass, you can use the original `AsyncSubject` class.

Comment: Was looking for something similar, thanks for pointing it out ! All is flowing perfectly now, you are a true Jest wizard !

Comment: While I have your attention, is it a better practice to mock all functions of a module in unit-testing (to have self-contained tests) ?